# How to get a consistent "perceived" color on a transparent BG?

Tags: color, transparency, controls

I'm in a pickle.

I have to make form controls (buttons, checkboxes, text inputs, etc.) on a semi transparent black background (85% alpha).

Here's what they look like so far:

[image: Le checkboxes]

Notice the difference between the top two and the bottom two. The difference is the bottom and right border is just light enough to give that cool inset look. The problem? All but one of those borders is the same color.

[image: :(]

Because it's on a transparent background, the lines appear to your eye as either lighter or darker based on the color behind it! So, that neat inset look will come and go based on what's under it. I always want the neat inset look to be there, how can I do it? Are there any blend mode tricks for this?

P.S. I forgot to mention that this will eventually get to be displayed in Flash, so I get to have a little fun with blend modes and stuff.

*Edit:* I made another image to better clarify the issue (by 'too dark' and 'too bright' I am still referring to the right and bottom borders).

[image: Another Example]

Comment: This reminds me of what it's like to paint a room in a pale colour when the previous colour is dark. The trick is to first paint it with white (or a very pale colour) and /then/ use the colour you want. You might find you need to add a div behind what you're showing, and set that to a non-transparent, consistent, colour.

Comment: Haha thanks for the real-world example. The problem is putting a layer of white paint would lose my cool transparent look.

Comment: This seems to me that you are looking for some sort of technical solution. Is that correct?

Comment: @Charles Technical solution, magic solution. Something like that. If your technical solution is minimally cpu intensive in Flash than I'm all for it.

Comment: if you're looking for a technical solution, you should probably try StackOverflow, not here. This isn't really the place for technical questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a screen or color dodge blending mode. Or, you could just use a pure white color but set the border area's transparency to to the percentage you want it to lighten. This will be the same as using a screen blending mode with a grey color of that luminosity.

**Edit:**
Perceived luminosity is based on the BG color the FG color is backdropped against—as you've seen in your images. Right now what is happening is that your checkbox highlights are rendered in the same color and shade no matter what the background is. So if the background is bright, it's only increasing the luminosity a little or none at all, but if the background is dark, then it's increasing the luminosity by a lot. This gives the highlight an unnatural/inconsistent look.

The fix is to make the highlights brighten the BG by X%, so that it will always be X% brighter than its adjacent pixels. The "perceived" luminosity will then be X%, regardless of the background (unless the background is too bright, then it won't be able to increase the brightness by the full X%).

Comment: See, that's the problem. The "percentage I want to lighten it" varies based off the color behind it--which I can't control. So what I'm asking is if there's a way to get a fixed perceived luminosity on varying background colors with some blend mode hackery.

Comment: @Jonathan: Are you sure that's what you really want? Because that would look really weird IMO.

Comment: Your edit is interesting. I did what you said in an example, but the results are the same--differing luminosities instead of an X% luminosity (check my edit).

Comment: @Jonathan: What blending mode are you using?

Comment: Tried it with both normal and screen (which should both be the same with 0x4cffffff)

Comment: @Jonathan: That's really weird--especially as the backgrounds seem to be the same for the left/right sides. Perhaps the blending modes in Flash are not the same as I'm used to in Photoshop, Illustrator and similar programs. Another possibility is that the blending isn't being applied in the right order. For instance, in Photoshop you need to manually enable the "Blend Interior Effects as Group" option when you want layer effects to blend with other layers using alternate blending modes. Otherwise, it gives unexpected results. I'm not sure if this might be in play here.